# Are there any open access journals in the cognitive sciences with impact factor >1

Tags: publication-process

[Impact factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor) are scores assigned to journals which indicate how often, on average, articles are cited. Impact factors [are published in Journal Citation reports of Thomson Reuters](http://thomsonreuters.com/products_services/science/science_products/a-z/journal_citation_reports/).

These reports however, do not indicate whether journals are open access or not.

I would like to know if there **is any open access journal** in the cognitive sciences with **impact factor >1**.

Comment: I am not too much into cogsci, but definitely there are 3 "generalistic" options: PlOS One, PlOS Biology and Nature Communications, all released under a CC licence. Many journals also give the possibility to authors to release their paper as open access.

Comment: You should consider asking this on [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I slightly adjusted your final question. Your question should be answered if you are linked to _any_ open access journal with impact factor > 1. Feel free to roll back, but I feel this will cause less controversy.

Answer (score 8):

[Frontiers](http://www.frontiersin.org) is an example of a collection of different open access journals where you find some high-impact publications within the cognitive science field. They have A LOT of journals within the [neuroscience](http://www.frontiersin.org/Neuroscience/about) and the [psychology](http://www.frontiersin.org/Psychology/about) field.

This is what Frontiers themselves says about impact factors of their journals:

> Thomson ISI requires at least three complete years of publishing, plus a few of other criteria, before issuing an impact factor for a specific journal. In the case of Frontiers, this condition has so far been met by only three of our Neuroscience journals. Impact factors are issued for the preceding year involving complex criteria that evaluate the previous three years' citations.
>
> The impact factor for Frontiers in Human Neuroscience was 1.58 in 2009
> and 1.94 in 2010, indicating substantial growth year over year. We
> expect to see this growth in Frontiers in Computational Neuroscience
> (2.58 in 2010) and Frontiers in Cellular Neuroscience (3.58 in 2010),
> as well as a number of impact factors issued to other Frontiers
> journals in 2012. We expect these impact factors to continue to rise
> in 2012 as well as to have Thomson ISI issue several more impact
> factors to Frontiers journals in June 2012.

So, in this case ["Frontiers in Human Neuroscience"](http://www.frontiersin.org/Human_Neuroscience), ["Frontiers in Computational Neuroscience"](http://www.frontiersin.org/Computational_Neuroscience) and ["Frontiers in Cellular Neuroscience"](http://www.frontiersin.org/Cellular_Neuroscience) would probably be three good answers to your question.

Comment: This is really useful. Be aware of the fee structure however: http://www.frontiersin.org/Neuroscience/fees

Comment: @JeromyAnglim What about it?

Answer (score 6):

Relatively specific for [Judgement and Decision Making](http://journal.sjdm.org/) the Journal (Impact factor: 1.632) of the JDM Society might be of interest.

Additionally the [Directory of Open Access Journals](http://www.doaj.org/) might be of interest.